# Телеграм бот отправляет сообщения всем пользователям в группе

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добра!
Добавили бота в группу, при нажатии на кнопку любой участник группы получает ответ на запрос другого участника в общем чате, получается какая то вакханалия, помогите пожалуйста, как это исправить(Нужно чтоб другие участники группы не видели этого)? Если это невозможно, то как одно из решений: отправлять в личные сообщения, тоже нужна помощь.

Пример кода:

```
@dp.message_handler(text='Какое число?')
async def buttons_test(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'Салют {message.from_user.full_name}! \n'
                         f'Ты выбрал число {message.text}')
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не был виден, не знаю. Отправка личных сообщений: используй send_message и передавай id пользователя и текст сообщения.